# How to automatically and programmatically follow wechat OA after using wechat login API?

Tags: wechat

User flow

1. User clicks on wechat link on the website
2. User is redirected to the wechat QR code for logging in to the web site.
3. User logs in to the website successfully after scanning the QR code.

After successful logging in, I want users to automatically subscribe/follow the OA(subscription account).
Can you please let me know if its possible and if possible can you please guide me to the relevant resource to achieve this functionality

Answer (score 0):

Although I do not know of any guide pointing how to do that, I implemented it myself for a woocommerce-based site.

- user lands on the page
- the system authenticates the user (with the WeChat User Info interface `https://api.weixin.qq.com/sns/userinfo`)
- the system checks if the user is a follower (with the WeChat User Info interface `https://api.weixin.qq.com/sns/userinfo`)
- if the user is not a follower, a QR code to follow the OA is displayed (QR code pulled from the weChat interface `https://mp.weixin.qq.com/cgi-bin/showqrcode`)
- the user scans the code and follows
- the system receives an "subscribed" event (XML event)
- the system checks the last page visited by the user
- the system sends a welcome message to the user (XML response of type news)
- the user interacts with the welcome message to go back to the original page

Comment: you can checkout `https://h5.acewill.net/?qrcode=m14423754199706` - that's also the approach they took (best opened in WeChat browser)